# Fixing m4 on MAC OS 10.14.5

Tags: macos, gnu, m4, phpize

I'm having an issue with pecl which is erring out saying phpize had failed.

The problem ultimately seems to be with m4. Error is autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4

When I run "which m4" I get /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4

However, any command I try to run with m4 like "m4 --version" I get the following:

Abort trap:  6

I can't find a good explanation of that error, but I'm guessing something is corrupted with m4, but I can't figure out how to fix this on a Mac. Do I just download a newer version and run configure, make and make install? Just a little nervous since I have somewhat limit Mac experience.

Comment: If you use **homebrew** as your package manager, you can install a newer `m4` with `brew install m4` and be sure to put `/usr/local/bin` at the front of your PATH so the **homebrew** version of `m4` runs in preference to Apple's version.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me a waring that said **m4 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.** So I was a little reluctant to do that.

Comment: The Apple one in `/usr/bin/m4` works fine. You seem to be running one that comes with MAMP. Maybe you need to move the MAMP part of your PATH **after** `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. Turned out to be easier than I thought. I got confused between the MAMP version and the Apple version thinking they were related for some reason.

Comment: Sorry how did you resolve it?

Comment: please can you help with a clearer understanding of what you did to resolve this

Comment: For me, reinstalling m4 using homebrew and installing autoconf and automake via homebrew solved the issue.
`brew install autoconf automake libtool m4`
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed similar issue by executing `brew reinstall m4`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a "brew (re)install m4", I had to temporarily remove "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin" from my PATH.  After that this worked for me.

Comment: Get m4 path with:

 `brew info m4`


Move the MAMP m4:

 `mv /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4_old`


Create a link:

 `ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/m4/bin/m4 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4`

   ^ using the path returned in first commands.